# How to change the number of columns in JQuery Masonry?

Tags: javascript, jquery-masonry, masonry

I see no option in JQuery Masonry :  http://masonry.desandro.com/ to change the number of columns In tumblr  ? It is always 2 But I want it 3, And width of the page is 1000px so it is okay to be 3 columns. Can you suggest to me anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Masonry doesn't typically concern itself with deciding how many columns there should be: it just helps to fit pieces together based on your existing CSS styles. So if you set all your elements' widths so that they would fit three-across on the page, then masonry should be able to help them fit together more smoothly.

It's not really clear what tumblr has to do with this, sorry.

Comment: hmmmm....tumblr do nothing to this. But i thought it depends on the page width or div width.

Comment: @MuhammadJuma'a: That's right: it depends on the container width and the width of the items in the container. If those items would naturally fit three-wide, then they should fit while using masonry too. Perhaps even though your page is 1000px, you've surrounded the tiles in a container that has a smaller width?

Comment: YES, All surrounded in a container, And that's my problem, That's why I am asking.

Comment: Then... can you change the container size? Perhaps you should share a code sample or jsfiddle or something. It's not really clear to me what aspect of this is causing you trouble.